# HTMLAgilityPack get innerText of a td tag with an id attribute

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack, nodes, html-table

I am trying to select the inner text of a td with an id attribute with the HTMLAgilityPack.

Html Code:

```
<td id="header1">    5    </td>
<td id="header2">    8:39pm    </td>
<td id="header3">    8:58pm    </td>
...
```

Code:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

doc.LoadHtml(data);

var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@id='header1']");

if (nodes != null)
{
    foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(node.InnerText);
    }
}
```

I keep getting null nodes because I am not selecting the td tag correctly but cannot figure out what I have done wrong...

Edit:

I made a mistake with header1 and header2, but there are 5 different td tags with headers 1 to 5.

Comment: Did you check those IDs you have taken. `<td id="header2">` and you are retrieving from **`(//td[@id='header1'");`**

Comment: In html, the id is `header2` while in code, it is specified as `header1`.

Comment: Your code seems correct. Can you post your data somewhere?

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to select `header1` but the id is `header2`.

You could also use `GetElementById` directly:

```
var td = doc.GetElementbyId("header2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. I don't think you're doing anything wrong. Your code should give you only the `<td>` with `id="header1"`. If you have, let's say, from `header1` to `header5`, you can do:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++ ) {
    var tdNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//td[@id='header{0}']", i));

    //do something with the node here
}
```

although I suggest you posting your entire code, so that we can tell you why you're getting `null`, and also a better way of parsing the `<td>` nodes without doing the above loop (eg. something like `//tr[@id='some-id']//td[contains(@id, 'header')]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can Solve your Problem by using the InnerHtml Property Like:

```
var td = doc.GetElementbyId("header2").InnerHtml;
```